# Advanced conditions with class-validator (possible)?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, ajv, class-validator

I have TypeScript NestJS project.

I need to validate incoming DTO to my API. It can be described as "creating of project" where we have type of building (House, Flat, Garden) and depending on that type we need to define:

- House: FLOORS including ROOMS
- Flat: ROOMS
- Garden: nothing (it is one "room")

Example of house type:

```
{
  type: HOUSE,
  floors: [
    {
      name: "1st floor",
      rooms: [
        {
          name: "bedroom"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Example of flat type:

```
{
  type: FLAT,
  rooms: [
    {
      name: "bedroom"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've done this in past with help of `AJV`, but now as we migrated to NestJS, we started using `class-validator`.

My question is, if I can make those advanced conditionals (eg. when type is FLAT, then expect ROOMS only, but not FLOORS) in `class-validator`?

Answer (score 6):

With `class-validator` you have the options of [Conditional Validation](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#conditional-validation) and of [Group Validation](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-groups), or you could always create a custom pipe and use AJV as you are used to. For the conditional validation you could create validations based on `type` and then let class-validator take care of the rest

Comment: "you could create validations based on type", can you show an example?

Comment: @coler-j if I can figure out what I was meaning, then absolutely. I'm pretty sure I've seen examples _somewhere_, but I can't recall where at the moment

Comment: This doesn't help at all. I'm also want to do the same thing. I only find basic examples which are all just copies from docs and nothing more advanced like the example in question. Saying there are "examples somewhere" doesn't say much as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a custom validator for that. The docs are pretty good:
https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-classes

When you create your custom validator class, in your implementation of `validate` you can access the other parameter beeing validated in the `args` argument. Just write your if statements and return false if they are not met. You can even return your custom error messages and implement your own decorator.

Answer (score 1):

I use this kind of validation for nasted objects:

```
export class PredefinedProductsDao {

  @IsEnum(ProductEnum)
  product: ProductEnum;

  @IsObject()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type((type: TypeHelpOptions | undefined) => {
    if (type?.object) {
      const predefinedProductsDao: PredefinedProductsDao =
        type.object as PredefinedProductsDao;
      switch (predefinedProductsDao.editor) {
        case ProductEnum.FIRST:
          return FirstProductDao;
        case ProductEnum.SECOND:
          return SecondProductDao;
      }
    }
    return FirstProductDao;
  })
  predefinedConfig: FirstProductDao | SecondProductDao;
}
```

In my case I want validate `predefinedConfig` to be one of DAOs, different for each product. It's working as a shae

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirements. If you're okay to nest the incoming object by one level, following pattern should work.

```
import { ValidateNested, IsNotEmptyObject } from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

class MyRequestDto {
  @IsNotEmptyObject()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(null, {
    keepDiscriminatorProperty: true,
    discriminator: {
      property: 'type',
      subTypes: [
        {
          name: 'Flat',
          value: Flat,
        },
        {
          name: 'Room',
          value: Room,
        },
        {
          name: 'Garden',
          value: Garden,
        },
      ],
    },
  })
  entity: Flat | Room | Garden;
}
```

We can use the `Type` decorator provided by the class-transformer and pass in the `discriminator` option, which takes the `property` and `subTypes` attributes.

- `property` is the propertyName to use for establishing the type of incoming of the incoming object.
- `subTypes` will have the corresponding value (`name`) for the property and the class (`value`) to use for validation.

The interface definition can be found [here](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/master/src/interfaces/decorator-options/type-discriminator-descriptor.interface.ts)

Comment: `TS2345: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type '((type?: TypeHelpOptions | undefined) => Function) | undefined'.` How did it work for you?

Comment: @mike927 use `() => Object` instead